# Is it ok to turn off the fridge for a few hours for defrosting?

Tags: refrigerator

I havent been able to locate a seperate off switch for the freezer compartment, I dont think there is one. So the only solution would be to turn off the whole freezer+fridge combination.

Would it be safe for the food inside the fridge for the whole thing to be off for a few hours so I can defrost the freezer?

I tried placing hot water inside the freezer while it was still on, wasnt very effective.

Answer (score 1):

The [US FDA](http://www.fda.gov/Food/ResourcesForYou/Consumers/ucm077023.htm) says that an unopened fridge should keep food for about [4 hours](http://www.fda.gov/Food/ResourcesForYou/Consumers/ucm076881.htm) before it starts to spoil. This time is reduced if the fridge wasn't already cold, or if warm food was recently placed into it and hasn't cooled down. It'll also be reduced if the seals or insulation on the fridge is bad. Not sure how much defrosting you'll get in 2 or 3 hours though...

Comment: Sounds good to me some times with older coil based freezers when the power is off and the pressure in the loop increases there is a reverse cooling / heating of the main coils (freezer) so it starts to melt from the inside and a pan of hot water with the door open will help the outside, the cool stuff in the fridge will help hold the temp if you are concerned add several 3/4 full plastic bottles of water to the freezer the day before or get a pound of dry ice and wrap in news paper bottles or dry ice in the fridge just before turning power off.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a bag of ice and put into the fridge veggies plastic bins for a peace of mind.
That should give you a day.

Good Luck

Comment: Or, instead of buying a bag of ice, just take whatever was in your freezer and chuck it in your fridge for the interim!